# Reconcile jQuery syntax inconsistency

Tags: jquery, syntax

I seem to have trouble remembering when to use `<element>` (with brackets) and when to use `element` (without brackets) when working with jQuery. Compare for example the adding and then removing of an `option` from a `select`:

```
$("#items").append( $('<option>', {value:"third", text:"Third"}) );
$("#items").find('option').remove();
```

The `append` method requires the brackets, whereas the `find` method does not. How to reconcile this inconsistency?

Thanks.

Comment: Simply speaking, first is used for creating new HTML elements, second is the selector. Or what is the question?

Comment: you might want to use self closing tag when creating an element with jquery like `$('<option/>',{value:'third'})`

Comment: Also, those are elements, not attributes...

Comment: @VisioN: The question was why don't the creation and the selector have the same format.

Comment: @dotancohen The answer is simple: to distinguish. `$("option")` and `$("<option>")` do different things. I don't know what else to add :)

Comment: I realise that `$("option")` selects "option" elements. What does `$("<option>")` do? Create "option" elements? If so, then why do the selection and the creation syntaxes differ?

Comment: @3nigma: Why would one use self-closing tags with an option, which is not self-closing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use the brackets when you are creating new elements, just like you use the brackets when you write HTML.

You don't use brackets when you are selecting existing elements, just like you don't use brackets when you select elements in CSS.